# Lightweight logistic function

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I have a value $X$ that ranges between $[0, 100]$, and I would like to apply some "activation function" on it...

Let me explain.
Currently if i take just the value $X$, and use it as it is, I will get something like $f(x) = x$ obviously as "transformation function", but I would like to apply to $X$ some kind of function, that is "centered" on $50$ and that it limited on $[0, 100]$, something like:
$$f(50) = 50$$
$$f(0) \approx 0$$
$$f(100) \approx 100$$

and that the "graph" of that function is similar to the logistic function graph:
[image: logistic function]

However, I can't use the logistic function, since I need to perform this transformation in real-time, and $e^{-x}$ is very computational intensive, and so i was looking to a similar function, that uses more lightweight operators / functions

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ works good too for logictic models

Comment: @LuisFelipe yes I've already tried using it, but it's also very intensive as calculation

Comment: what about logistic function using $e^x$ as a truncated form? i.e $\sum_{k=0}^{5} x^k / k!$

Comment: protiop: try to normalize your data before applying logictic function, also normalize data helps models to converge in neural netoworks. If you are using python, use a vectorized functionfor improve time execution

Comment: @LuisFelipe i'll try the approximation, but what you mean with "normalize"? I came from a statistic course where normalization means the make it range between 0 and 1, like I suppose the vectors in algebra... but i can't see how this would help when applying the activation function, since it has $R$ as domain, and so normalizing it won't help, if not even make thing worse

Comment: When I work with neural networks and I have to use activation functions like logistic, I convert the data at scale $[0,1]$ for two reasons: 1. To avoid overflow in operations and have wrong results, 2. To help model to converge. If you have vectors just do $\frac{v}{||v||}$